# Enlarging VirtualBox HD ..How to handle?

Tags: virtualbox, hard-drive

my problem:

With the virtualbox manager in my xubuntu 20.04 I could enlarge the virtual HD for my Windows7 VBx OS.

In my VBx-Win7 directory I cannot see the enlarged amount of my virtual HD??!

Any idea how to fix this problem?

I would appreciate very much any Idea.

Greeting

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I see there is no Ubuntu related problem in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the virtual win7 area

```
open system (Systemsteuerung)

     admin (Verwaltung)

     memory (Datenträger)

expand your systempartition
```